# Is a "complete" cipher possible?

Tags: cr.crypto-security, cryptographic-attack

Is a "complete" symmetric cipher possible?  By this I mean a symmetric cipher that is provably secure under the assumption that a secure symmetric cipher exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use Levin universal search to construct a "universal one-way function" (e.g., [these lecture notes](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs687/2006fa/lectures/lecture5.pdf)). From this one-way function you can then construct symmetric-key encryption primitives (pseudorandom generators, block ciphers, CPA/CCA-secure encryption) using standard theoretical constructions.

One-way function $\to$ pseudorandom generator:

> Håstad, J., Impagliazzo, R., Levin, L.A. and Luby, M., 1999. A pseudorandom generator from any one-way function. SIAM Journal on Computing, 28(4), pp.1364-1396.

Pseudorandom generator $\to$ pseudorandom function:

> Goldreich, O., Goldwasser, S. and Micali, S., 1986. How to construct random functions. Journal of the ACM (JACM), 33(4), pp.792-807.

Pseudorandom generator $\to$ block cipher / pseudorandom permutation:

> Luby, M. and Rackoff, C., 1988. How to construct pseudorandom permutations from pseudorandom functions. SIAM Journal on Computing, 17(2), pp.373-386.

Block cipher $\to$ CCA-secure encryption:

> CBC mode + CBC-MAC

Comment: Couldn't one use the PRF directly as a stream cipher with a Carter-Weigman MAC?

Comment: Yes, once you have a PRF there are many options available. :)

Comment: For improved efficiency, one can directly use "universal search to construct a" "universal PRF". ​ ​